# How do I make a DVD copy using two optical drives?

Tags: video

What is the simplest procedure for copying a DVD video to a blank dual layer DVD disk?  I have Windows 7 and two optical drives; the drive with the blank DVD disk supports dual layer disks.

Comment: It just seems like it should be quicker and simpler to record directly from the first (player) optical device to the second (recording) optical device, without having to create any sort of file in the computer.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this link](http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-copy-dvd-another-dvd-using-single-dvd-drive/#.WJTCrxuLSUk)

The method depends on what you want to do and what types of files you want to copy.

First, copy all the files from your source DVD to a new folder on your desktop.  I created a simple folder called Files to Burn and dropped a few items inside.

Then pop in a blank DVD and wait a few seconds for the Windows AutoPlay feature to detect it.

If AutoPlay doesn’t appear in 10 seconds, open Windows Explorer (Windows Key + e) and click the DVD drive in the left pane under Computer.

Copying a file to a DVD

Choose Burn files to disc then give the disc a title and choose With a CD/DVD player.

I now empower you to drag and drop your files from your Desktop folder into the DVD burning window that shows desktop.ini.

Click the Burn to disc button and you should be all set.

**NOTE:** This is for one dvd drive which would be a lot easier.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.